# Storing a global variable that holds a collection of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to store a global variable so I don't hit the database each time I reference the models.

Should I do this in an initializer or is there another way?

```
$rules = Rule.all
```

This data will never change unless I change the codebase so it is fine to only be refreshed when the app reloads.

What options do I have?

I think I can do this also in my controller:

```
$rules ||= Rule.all
```

Is there a "best practise" concerning this?

Comment: That is a bad idea. Well first need to know why do you want cache the value? Do you want to cache the value on boot up?

Comment: If the data is static, why use a database instead of a simple Ruby hash or array?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes on bootup.

Comment: @meagar Because it is managed from the db, but it is static once the site is running.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, then inside the `config/initializers/` directory create a file like  `load_rules.rb`. And inside that, write something like:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  RULES = Rule.all
end
```

Now use this constant anywhere you want to use.

Comment: Why should he even use ActiveRecord Objects when he's not doing anything with the database?

Comment: @RaVeN He used the term _model_ . The line _I want to store a global variable so I don't hit the database each time I reference the models_ is enough for me to conclude into this solution. But as I said in your answer comment, for static data no need model. I notice the design smell later.

Comment: Wait so you're saying that a 'model' is always an ActiveRecord model?

Comment: I don't think anything is smelly about the design.  The state is managed in the db, but it is static once the site is running.

Comment: @RaVeN Man, really don't want to argue on this. 100 people can mean 100 things, I don't bother. And please don't argue on this.

Comment: @Blankman I am just saying different possibilities. Some people will use YAML for static data and load then in constant. People choice it is. But there are options I am saying to build the same thing. If you are having the data inside the table, I would go with the solution I gave.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not arguing, I'm just saying that a model does not have to be something inside the DB. I was just asking myself why to use the DB to store static values like these 

Comment: Because they may not be that static after all. Because their ids could be used for referential integrity with other tables. Because you might want all your operational data in one place. Just some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using low-level caching wrapped in a method:

```
class ApplicationCotroller < ActionController::Base
  # ...

    def all_rules
      Rails.cache.fetch("all_rules") do
        Rule.all
      end
    end

  # ...
end
```

Depending on your use case the method could be placed in a singleton class instead of `ApplicationController` or in a mixin `Module`.

The main benefit of this approach is you can easily reload the rules without restarting the server by deleting the cache key from the console. Although you clearly marked this as a non-critical aspect, I think it adds some convenience.

Comment: I liked your cache approach! +1 . The reason is we can refresh the data without reboot. Good idea!

Comment: But 1 thing is what if I want to use it in some other context? You probably need to put inside some initializer kind, for global access.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, depending on the use case it can be placed somewhere else, an initializer is one option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to use the database for such a thing. You should store these values as an array of objects and use the `Rails.app.config.x` namespace:

so your model would look like:

```
#app/models/rule.rb
class Rule
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name:)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

and your initializer:

```
# config/initializers/rules_initializer.rb
Rails.application.config.x.rules = [
                                      Rule.new(name: "Admin"),
                                      ...
                                     ]
```

Comment: This approach would require modifying the code when the rule set changes.

Comment: @NicNilov How would you not change any code if the set changed? store it in the db?

Comment: @ArupRakshit seeds.rb should only be used to populate the database, not in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I read something in the OP's post, which I overlooked. I focused on he has a model and want to load then on boot. He has some static data, so model is not needed, if it is just to display data.

Comment: @RaVeN From the question text it is clear that `Rule` is already a model stored in the database. So yes, store it in the db.

Comment: It was just an idea to not store this in de DB, you can export your code into that file and use a simpler way without hitting the database  It's definitely fine to store it in the DB but I wouldn't do that as there is no use case for this because you're not querying or something, you know what I mean? @NicNilov

Comment: @RaVeN See my comment on Arup Rakshit's answer for possible use cases for that.